# Isolated singularities of harmonic mappings

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Can a homeomorphic harmonic mapping $f=(u,v,w):\Omega\to \Omega'$ have isolated singular points. Here $\Delta f =0$, and singular point is a point with zero Jacobian. This will extend Lewy theorem for q.c. harmonic mappings.

Comment: Where in the question are the polynomials of degree 3 promised in the title?

Comment: Maybe you could also explain why this question is interesting, i.e., where does it arise naturally?  Otherwise, it appears to be a random question that probably won't provoke much of any response.